# Determine if $R,\tau$ is a compact set

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I'd like to solve this exercise just by using the definition on compact set.

> Let $\tau(\mathcal{B})$ the topology generated by the basis $\mathcal{B}=\bigl\{[a,b)\,:\, a,b\in\mathbb{R}\wedge a<b\bigr\}$.
>
> Decide if $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ is a compact set

---

Let $\mathcal{R}=\cup_{i \in I }$ {$A_i$} be an open-cover of $\mathbb{R}$, with $A_i=[c,d), c <d$. Then I can't cover $(-\infty,+\infty)$ with a finite numbers of $A_i$, so the set is not compact.

Comment: You can also give a specific example: $C=\{[n,n+1): n\in \mathbb Z\}$ is an infinite open cover which is irreducible: No proper subset of $C$ is a cover, as the members of $C$ are pair-wise disjoint and not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is mostly correct. You can be more precise by defining $A_i = [i,i+1)$. Then $\Bbb R\subset \bigcup_{i\in\Bbb Z}[i,i+1)$, and you should take $\{A_i\}$ as your cover. For any finite subcover of $\{A_i\}$, the sets do not cover $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Thanks so much ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are not being precise about the definition of $\mathcal R$. One possibility is to take $\mathcal{R}=\{[n,n+1)\,|\,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Then, I suppose that it is clear that $\mathcal R$ has no finite subcover. Actually, it has *no* subcover besides itself.

Comment: Clear, thanks so much ! ;)